# How does the power button shut the computer down without root permission?

Tags: root, gui, shutdown

When I try to shutdown the computer from a command line or terminal I must have root privileges:

```
amy@amy:~$ shutdown now
shutdown: Need to be root
```

and

```
amy@amy:~$ halt
halt: Need to be root
```

but when shutting down using the graphical user interface, i.e. shutdown button, or the hardware shutdown button, I'm not asked for the password to do so. What does that shutdown for the graphical interface, and why it doesn't need the password or root privileges?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 Natty.

Comment: See [How does gnome reboot without root privileges?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/216818)

Comment: because if an attacker has physical access to your computer, you've lost already. Attempting to prevent someone who is within arms reach of the box from doing almost anything is at best a delaying tactic and mostly causes more inconvinience for day-to-day users than it would for an attacker. Most Linux distros will give you a root prompt if spoken to sternly during bootup for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The hardware power button triggers an ACPI event that `acpid` (the ACPI daemon) notices and reacts to; in this case by shutting down the system, although you could have it do whatever you want. The ACPI daemon runs as root, so it has permission to shutdown the system. Desktop environments (e.g. `gdm` for Gnome) typically run as root as well, so I suspect they work the same way -- you don't have permission to shutdown the system, but you can tell `gdm` you want it shut down and it can do it on your behalf

Comment: is it secure?? 'you could have it do whatever you want.'

Comment: To get `acpid` to do something different than it already does, you'd have to be root, so you'd already have permission to do insecure things. It is also possible to use MAC systems like SELinux to protect `acpid`, restricting the things they are allowed to do, even while they run as root.

Comment: @amyassin Well, to change what it does you need root privileges; a normal user can't tell it what to do. But `acpid` is configurable, it can run different scripts depending on the hardware events it sees (for example, I have `acpid` lock my computer when I hit the power button)

Comment: @amyassen If someone has physical access to your machine then it's too late to worry about security -- if the power button doesn't trigger a graceful shutdown they can just pull the power cord and cause an *ungraceful* shutdown.

Comment: @Shadur I mean if some malicious software could crack in somehow,, this can be a weak point... Though can't think how that malicious software can get in... Just wondered...

Comment: Said 'malicious software' would have to get root ownership and SUID permissions in order to tell init to make with the shutdown -- and again, by the time it gets to that point you have bigger problems to worry about than a possible shutdown.

Comment: This is a great answer, but most modern desktop environments actually use `dbus` rather than invoking a shutdown themselves.

Answer (score 11):

Michael's answer correctly discusses system function when using the hardware power switch, but most desktop environments actually use `dbus` for this purpose rather than doing it themselves. For example, GNOME uses `dbus`'s `org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Shutdown` when the shutdown button is clicked. When this is sent, `dbus` does some checks to determine whether the user sending the message is authorised to perform a shutdown, and if they are, it shuts down the system.

You can emulate this by using `dbus-send`. For example, to shut down your system using `dbus`, use something like this:

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Shutdown
```