# How do I hibernate my PC when I press the power button

Tags: linux, hibernate

Is there any way to make my PC hibernate when I press the power button? Obviously when I press this button somewhere some signal is sent. Can it be intercepted to enable my PC to hibernate?

Comment: Searching for "power button" on this site yielded [this helpful answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18503/how-does-the-power-button-shut-the-computer-down-without-root-permission/18504#18504) that includes the needed pointer to `acpid` which is also explained [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acpid) where you find references to for example `pm-utils` which might also help.

Comment: @sr_: Does this daemon come with all linux distros, or do I have to install it by myself?

Comment: I guess it's really common among Linux distributions.  What's yours? Look at `ps aux | grep acpid`, it might already be running.

Comment: Assuming you use `acpid` and `pm-utils`, [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acpid#Tips_.26_Tricks) can easily be adjusted to your needs.

Comment: @sr_: `acpid` is a (*the*?) correct way to handle this kind of events, so I guess you can write one of your comments as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably (could) use `acpid` (check via `ps aux | grep acpid`).  Then have a look at [this article in the ArchWiki explaining how to use `pm-utils` to extend `acpid`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acpid#Tips_.26_Tricks) to easily achieve whatever effect you'd like when some hardware button is pressed.

If, however, you use GNOME, there other (also GUI) ways, [see this comprehensive thread on `askubuntu.com`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71494/how-do-i-configure-an-action-when-pressing-hardware-power-button)