# How does gnome reboot without root privileges?

Tags: linux, systemd, reboot, polkit

I am reading the book [Linux kernel development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672329468), in chapter 5 "System Call Implementation" page 77 says

> For example, capable(CAP_SYS_NICE) checks whether the caller has the
>   ability to modify nice values of other processes. By default, the
>   superuser possesses all capabilities and nonroot possesses none. For
>   example, here is the reboot() system call. Note how its first step is
>   ensuring that the calling process has the CAP_SYS_REBOOT . If that one
>   conditional statement were removed, any process could reboot the
>   system.

However, in my Debian Sid I can reboot my machine by using gnome or by executing /sbin/reboot without sudo or su.
How is this possible?

Maybe with systemctl?

```
ls -l /sbin/reboot 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jun 28 04:23 /sbin/reboot -> /bin/systemctl
```

EDIT: My user groups

```
[damian@xvz:~]$ groups 
damian sudo wireshark bumblebee
```

EDIT 2: systemctl permissions

```
[damian@xvz:~]$ ls -l /bin/systemctl 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 626640 Jun 28 04:23 /bin/systemctl
```

Comment: Maybe *is* `systemctl`.  What does `ls -l /bin/systemctl` tell you?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is done via an authorization manager called [`polkit`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html):

> polkit provides an authorization API intended to be used by privileged
>   programs (“MECHANISMS”) offering service to unprivileged programs
>   (“SUBJECTS”) often through some form of inter-process communication
>   mechanism.

With `systemd` and `polkit` users with non-remote session can issue power related commands.  You can list all `polkit` registered actions and get details about any of them with `pkaction` (invoked with no arguments it will list all action ids).
In this particular case the action id is `org.freedesktop.login1.reboot` so if you run:

```
pkaction --action-id org.freedesktop.login1.reboot --verbose
```

the output should be something like:

```
org.freedesktop.login1.reboot:
  description:       Reboot the system
  message:           Authentication is required for rebooting the system.
  vendor:            The systemd Project
  vendor_url:        http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd
  icon:              
  implicit any:      auth_admin_keep
  implicit inactive: auth_admin_keep
  implicit active:   yes
```

Here, `active:  yes` means the user in the active session is authorized to 
reboot the system (details about implicit authorizations on `polkit` page). You can check if your session is active with:

```
loginctl show-session $XDG_SESSION_ID --property=Active
```

```
Active=yes
```

Comment: that mean any program I run can reboot my machine without my permission?

Comment: @osdamv - just like any program you run could `rm -rf` your user files...

Comment: @osdamv Note that you could run all programs you don't trust using `sudo --user=jimmy` where the user `jimmy` does *not* have the right to execute that polkit command...

Comment: How do I actually run this pkaction?

Comment: @Geremia - I don't understand the question.

Comment: @don_crissti I figured it out: `dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit" /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Restart`