# How do permissions work with the GUI

Tags: permissions, gui, session, privileges, architecture

There are several things that you must have superuser privileges to do from a terminal that can be done from a normal user account via the gui. e.g.

- Poweroff/reboot
- mount/unmount media

I understand why this is useful, but how exactly does this work without sufficient permission?

*edit:*

A comment suggest that I look at `polkit` and it seems that `pkexec` can be used to elevate privileges for certain commands. Is this how the things are executed through the gui?

Comment: Some search keywords: policykit, d-bus.

Comment: See [How does gnome reboot without root privileges?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/216818)

Answer (score 1):

### [PC-BSD](http://www.pcbsd.org/)

Approaches include `pc-su`. You can read a little about this [in the Handbook for 10.2](http://web.pcbsd.org/doc-archive/10.2/html/controlpanel.html#easypbi-settings), and [in the forums](https://forums.pcbsd.org/thread-17454.html):

> Both "sudo" and "pc-su" are used in different situations:
>
> pc-su: This simple script simply looks for an available GRAPHICAL utility that can be used for switching user permissions. Some of the utilities that it looks for are: kdesu (for KDE desktops), gksu (for GNOME/XFCE desktops), and qsu (which is a Qt switch-user utility that was written just for PC-BSD). This is generally only used when you are graphically starting up an application that required administrator privileges (like a PBI from the application menu for instance) since we do not want to require command-line usage for graphical operations.
>
> sudo: This is used only in scripts and/or command line application initializations because it either depends upon user input into the terminal or does not require a password at all (a couple of our utilities are setup this way, like the mounttray and life-preserver).
>
> So both "pc-su" and "sudo" are perfectly valid methods of switching user permissions, they just have different use-cases on a PC-BSD system.
>
> ~ Ken Moore ~
>   PC-BSD/iXsystems

– 2013-08-27

---

```
$ freebsd-version ; man pc-su
11.0-CURRENTNOV2015
No manual entry for pc-su
$
```