# How does shutting down require sudo except when done through a GUI?

Tags: sudo, shutdown, administration

If I want to shut down my machine programmatically or on the terminal, I must do `sudo poweroff` or `sudo shutdown`.  If I want to shut down my machine through my window manager and desktop environment, I navigate to my application menu and click "shut down".  This does not require my password.  **How is this implemented?**

Comment: Exactly how it is implemented may depend on what GUI (desktop session) and distribution you are using, but see for example [How does gnome reboot without root privileges?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216818/how-does-gnome-reboot-without-root-privileges) and its related questions