# How can KDE reboot a Debian system?

Tags: debian, systemd, systemctl

I'm experimenting around with Debian and I'm wondering about their permissions concerning systemd and reboot. I made the following obersvations (Debian Buster with lightdm and i3 WM):

- The commands `poweroff` etc. map to `/sbin/poweroff` which is a link to `/bin/systemctl`
- `/bin/systemctl` has permissions `-r-s------` and is inaccessible to the user
- As a result, `systemctl poweroff` etc. will not work, not even `systemctl --user mycommand` will not work (unlike e.g. on Arch Linux).

However when I install KDE, I can poweroff and reboot from the menu without entering a password! I didn't find any useful answers online and I don't understand how this is possible. How do they achieve that?

Comment: KDE uses `polkit` like other DEs, please check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216818/how-does-gnome-reboot-without-root-privileges). In short: the GUI user is explicitly given the permission to perform these tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mechanism called "polkit" that is used to (among other things) allow the user logged into the machine locally to perform certain tasks that on a traditional unix system would require root, such as shutting the machine down, connecting to networks etc.

There is a more in-depth answer at [How does gnome reboot without root privileges?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216818/how-does-gnome-reboot-without-root-privileges?rq=1) , ignore the talk of gnome in the question, this mechanism is used across many different desktops.