# Why it is possible for normal users to power off computer?

Tags: privileges, halt

I used the command `poweroff` and unexpectedly the system went off. I didn't used `sudo` therefore I didn't expect computer to be turned off. Why it was possible for me to use this command without root privilege?

Comment: can you add what distribution and relative version are you using?

Comment: Poweroff and so requires root. They are typically installed with +s, i.e. even users can start it as root. However, only users within the "console" group have execute permission for that. This group is given only to interactive, console login shells, and not to remote logins. Thus, locally logged in users have this permission only. Probably there is some setting where you take it away even from them.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is alluded to in a comment on [Why does reboot and poweroff require root privileges?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253767/86440)

On some distributions using systemd, [`poweroff` is now a symlink to `systemctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/poweroff.html), which instructs systemd to shut the system down on behalf of the user, without asking for the password (if the user has sufficient privileges, typically indicated by the fact that they’re using a local session, *i.e.* they have physical access to the system).

See [What are the default Polkit privileges on Arch Linux for shutdown, halt, etc., and why are they so?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209766/86440) for details (not specific to Arch Linux).

Comment: So `ssh user@remoteHost poweroff` would fail where logging in locally would succeed?

Comment: @roaima , Yes, A simple test: `ssh user@localhost`, then `systemctl poweroff` will ask for root privileges.

Comment: @roaima yes, it will fail remotely.

Comment: ...have physical access to the system, usually including a physical power switch. :) And it's better to allow the user to shutdown cleanly through the UI, than to have them fall back to the power switch.

Comment: @ilkkachu exactly, I suspect that’s the reasoning here but I haven’t looked for a reference. Desktop environments don’t necessarily use the same mechanisms, they typically go through Policy Kit but the end result is the same.

Comment: I always have to chuckle when a computer I'm sitting at tries to tell me I can't turn it off. "Dude, you're plug's right over there. Watch this..."